# Difference between interface's full name and explicitly implemented it's property

Tags: c#

Explicitly implemented interface's properties usually starts with it's interface's full name. However if it is a nested interface, property's name will be a bit mismatch.

```c#
namespace NS
{
    public class Container
    {
        //FullName is NS.Container+ITest
        public interface ITest
        {
            int Prop { get; }
        }
    }

    public class Sample : Container.ITest
    {
        //Property's name is NS.Container.ITest.Prop
        int Container.ITest.Prop { get; }
    }
}
```

Why property's name is not `NS.Container+ITest.Prop`? Or interface would better be named `NS.Container.ITest`. It would be more correct, isn't it?

Comment: @Lorond: Now I don't see your question.

Comment: @SLaks Try to reflect this property, you will see `NS.Container.ITest.Prop` name but interface's full name will be `NS.Container+ITest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type names that the CLR generates simply don't match the naming conventions of the C# language.  The canonical example is `List<int>`, the CLR type name will resemble `List'1` (backquote).  Which is not a valid type identifier in C#, just like NS.Container+ITest is not valid either.

You need to use C# naming conventions in C# code.

Comment: I know that they don't match naming conventions. I just wonder if there any other naming conventions for that cases. Like `+` in `NS.Container+ITest` tells us that `ITest` belongs to class or struct named `Container`. Or private property `NS.ITest.Prop` would tell us that it's explicit implementation of `Prop` property for interface `NS.ITest`. It just for reflection purposes. I don't ever thought to use such names in my code. :)

Comment: There's lots of them, including names that the C# compiler itself generates for types that are not explicitly created in your code.  Like lamdas and iterators.  Listing them all seems a waste of time, given the odds I may well miss one.  I don't really get the point of the question, I guess.

Comment: The point of question is there is `.` in property's name `NS.Container.ITest.Prop` instead of `+`, like it's in interface name (`NS.Container+ITest`). I was expected `NS.Container+ITest.Prop` name for property and was surprised that it a bit different.

Comment: As I explained in the answer, the CLR type naming conventions just aren't the same.  The C# language is just one language it supports, there are dozens, all with different type naming conventions and restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that `NS.Container+ITest` indicates that ITest is a nested class under NS.Container then `NS.Container+ITest.Prop` would be the member of the interface. But the *implementation* of Prop is a member of Sample (that explicitly implements the interface) which matches the name `NS.Container.ITest.Prop`. Trying to access a member of an interface isn't possible, so resolving the name that matches implementation seems reasonable.

Comment: I don't see logic why Prop being member of Sample would match that name. Usually explicitly implemented member's name match interface's name it belongs to.